# Show message if username or password is invalid in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I have two route

```
app.route('/login')
.get(function (req, res) {
  res.render('formUser', {
    title: 'Login User',
    action: 'login',
    error: 'empty or full, depends on redirect'
  });
})
.post(function (req, res) {
   //some stuff
   //no user found then redirect
   res.redirect('/users/login');
});
```

How can I populate error with redirect from post Request?

I don't like `res.redirect('/users/login?erorr=username');` and check URL

Answer (score 2):

You could use [express-flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-flash) which is designed for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) for storing your error message.